# Why don't my radio buttons deselect when I click on another radio button?

Tags: html

Radio button aren't deselected when I choose another one.

```
<div style="margin: 40px 40px 5px 40px;">
      <form> 
        <div style="">
          <div style="float: left;"><input type="radio"></div>
          <div style="">
        <label style="font-size: 24px">Email my gift</label>
          <div style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 137%;">
  <p>Send my friend a gift email message, including all the info they'll need to get up and running on Viddir.</p>
  <p><label for="email_input">Recipient's email address</label></p>
          <p><input type="text" size="24"></p>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="radio">
    <label style="font-size: 24px;">Send gift through Viddir</label>
        <div style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 137%;">
      <p>Send my friend a gift message directly to their Viddir account.</p>
      <p style="font-style: italic;">Note: This option also sends an email message, to be sure your friend sees your gift as soon as possible.</p>
      </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="radio">
        <label style="font-size: 24px;">Save for later</label>
        <p style="font-size: 16px;">Save your gift for later. You can access it through the gifts tab.</p>
    </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div style="width: 116px; margin: 0 auto;">
      <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="btn btn-success btn-large">
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You waste your own time using `<br/>` for positioning.  Use CSS for fonts and sizes, put your `<label>` and <input>` elements in `<p>`paragraphs, give them some margin, and use `<fieldset>`s for related inputs.  It will be faster for you to write than what you are doing now.  All your `<input>`s need `name` attributes; that's how the data asre sent back to the server.

Comment: While all the extra code that is posted here may distract from the question, I think it is a perfectly reasonable question -- I had the exact same one just now, and the answer below answered it perfectly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Radios with the same `name` are treated as a group. When you select one button, all other buttons in the same group are unselected.

Comment: Oh cool, but how well will that work with PHP form handling?

Comment: That can be done with value?

Comment: @user2476551 I'm not sure what you mean by either of those questions.. The browser will submit the value of the selected radio with the name of the radio group.